# Understanding the speed difference in threading

Tags: python, python-multithreading, netmiko

This is the script both threading functions call:

```
def searchBadWireless( hub ):

    host = f'xxx.xxx.xxx.{hub}'
    results = {}
    try:
        netConnect = ConnectHandler( device_type=platform, ip=host, username=cisco_username, password=cisco_password, )

       output = netConnect.send_command( 'sh int status | i 298|299' )
       netConnect.disconnect()

       results[ int( hub ) ] = output
   except:
       print( f'{host} - Failed to connect' )
```

Now the first threading function I have completes in around 7 seconds:

```
def threadingProcess( execFunction ):

    switchList = getSwitchIPs()

    start = perf_counter()
    threads = []
    for ip in switchList:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=execFunction, args=( [ip[ 0 ]] ) )
        threads.append( thread )

    for t in threads:
        t.start()

    for c in threads:
        c.join()

    finish = perf_counter()
    print(f"It took {finish-start} second(s) to finish.")
```

But the second one I have runs at around 32 seconds:

```
def newThreadProcess():

    switchList = getSwitchIPs()

    start = perf_counter()

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(searchBadWireless, switchList)
        # for result in results:
            # print(result)

    finish = perf_counter()

    print(f"It took {finish-start} second(s) to finish.")
```

From what I have read online the better approach is the second function but why does it take so much longer to complete than the first, is there a way of speeding it up to be as fast as the first function?

Comment: What is the size of `switchList` and how many cores (`os.cpu_count()`) do you have?

Comment: @Fnaxiom - This is great, worked a treat and brought the time down to around 9 seconds, thanks a lot.

Comment: @RohitP - Virtual server with 2 cores mate

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I don't see @Fnaxiom's comment. I was going to say the exact same thing they said but asked for this information to fill it with some numbers. The default thread count calculation for ThreadPoolExecutor is `os.cpu_count + 4` up to a maximum of 32 if `max_workers` are not specified. Glad to know making the change they suggested worked for you. I would suggest limiting your thread count if the size of switchList could fluctuate on the higher side.

Comment: Yeah SO deleted it for some reason. I will put is as an answer for future references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function is faster for the simple reason that all threads are started immediately. If your work items are of number N, you are lunching N threads in parallel. If your machine can handle that load, it will be fast.
For the second function, the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, by default, limits the number of threads by using a `pool` of threads. In order to specify the pool size, you need to set the `max_workers` arguments to the target number of threads.

Doc:
*Changed in version 3.5: If max_workers is None or not given, it will default to the number of processors on the machine, multiplied by 5, assuming that ThreadPoolExecutor is often used to overlap I/O instead of CPU work and the number of workers should be higher than the number of workers for ProcessPoolExecutor.*

So it seems that the host had a low number of CPUs, thus limiting the number of threads in the pool. Theoretically, if the number of `max_workers` was equal to N (number of work items), the throughput of both functions would be the same.